# How to program a UIButton to move up based on height of dynamically sized label

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a UILabel which acts as a caption and expands vertically based on the length of user input. I have a button on top of the label acting as a name button. How do I program the button to move up as the label expands, to avoid overlap?

Comment: Use auto layout.

Comment: How do I set the constraints of the button to take into account the dynamic height of the label?

Comment: You don’t. You just pin it to the top of the label.

Comment: I'm doing everything programmatically so I guess I'll just have to get over the learning curve. That's great, thank you!

Comment: Autolayout is programmatic. No law says you have to have to a storyboard (most serious devs do not use one).

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps you as an example of a label and button as your question[image: uploaded gif to understand better just check this link]

Comment: Do note that the OP asking how to do this programmatically, not using a storyboard.